# Vertical Ray with Line Intersection

Tags: java, math, 2d, raytracing

I am making a 2D game in java and I am using 2D rays to cast shadows. I use this algorithm to find intersection between a ray and a line which i found here [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

```
// Returns 1 if the lines intersect, otherwise 0. In addition, if the lines 
// intersect the intersection point may be stored in the floats i_x and i_y.
char get_line_intersection(float p0_x, float p0_y, float p1_x, float p1_y, 
float p2_x, float p2_y, float p3_x, float p3_y, float *i_x, float *i_y)
{
   float s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
   s1_x = p1_x - p0_x;     s1_y = p1_y - p0_y;
   s2_x = p3_x - p2_x;     s2_y = p3_y - p2_y;

   float s, t;
   s = (-s1_y * (p0_x - p2_x) + s1_x * (p0_y - p2_y)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
   t = ( s2_x * (p0_y - p2_y) - s2_y * (p0_x - p2_x)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);

   if (s >= 0 && s <= 1 && t >= 0 && t<=1)
   {
       // Collision detected
       if (i_x != NULL)
           *i_x = p0_x + (t * s1_x);
       if (i_y != NULL)
           *i_y = p0_y + (t * s1_y);
       return 1;
   }

return 0; // No collision
}
```

The problem is that if the ray and the line are both vertical and both the ray and the line lay on the same line i need to get the point where the ray hits the line. For example intersection with ray starting from (10,10) to (10,30) and a line starting from (10,20) to (10,40) should give me (10,20) but it returns null instead.

This is my java code

```
public static Point2D.Double get_line_intersection(Line2D.Double ray, Line2D.Double line){
    double s1_x, s1_y, s2_x, s2_y;
    s1_x = ray.x2 - ray.x1;       s1_y = ray.y2 - ray.y1;
    s2_x = line.x2 - line.x1;     s2_y = line.y2 - line.y1;

    double s, t;
    s = (-s1_y * (ray.x1 - line.x1) + s1_x * (ray.y1 - line.y1)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);
    t = ( s2_x * (ray.y1 - line.y1) - s2_y * (ray.x1 - line.x1)) / (-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y);


    if (s >= 0 && s<=1 && t >= 0)
    {
        // Collision detected
        Point2D.Double intersection = new Point2D.Double();
        intersection.x = ray.x1 + (t * s1_x);
        intersection.y = ray.y1 + (t * s1_y);
        return intersection;
    }

    return null;
```

}

I only removed the condition t<=1 in the first if statement because the ray is infinite.

Comment: Try using a for-loop, iterating through values the different points on the lines.

Comment: But you can't iterate through the points on a line, because there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: Yes they are infinite and besides if it is even possible it would be too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to check whether your ray and segment are parallel - in this case cross product is zero:

```
(-s2_x * s1_y + s1_x * s2_y) = 0
```

If it is true, consider the first and the second cases from four ones, described in excellent answer at your link. You example is for 1st case (collinear objects)